# Parsing non iso datetime string to just date part in presto

Tags: presto

I have table which stores datetime as varchar
Format looks like this `2018-07-16 15:00:00.0` ,
I want to parse this to extract only date part so that I use date part to compare with date in string format such as '2018-07-20' in where clause. What is the best way to achieve this in presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular format (based on example value `2018-07-16 15:00:00.0` in the question) is understood by `cast` from `varchar` to `timestamp`. You then need to extract `date` part with another `cast`:

```
presto> SELECT CAST(CAST('2018-07-16 15:00:00.0' AS timestamp) AS date);
   _col0
------------
 2018-07-16
(1 row)
```